# Fastest Way to Match Column Values of Tables In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, `Table1` and `Table2`.

Suppose `Table1` have the following columns: `T1c1, T1c2, T1c3`
and `Table2` have the following columns: `T2c1, T2c2, T2c3`

I need to add values of `Table2.T2c3` to `Table1.T1c3` based on matching pairs between the two tables and their other two columns or just matching one column values if a column has `NULL` values in one table or both. That is, I need to match `Table1.T1c1` values with `Table2.T2c1` values and `Table1.T1c2` values with `Table2.T2c2` values or just match `Table1.T1c1` with `Table2.T2c1` values and etc if there's `NULL`.

The problem is, my tables are of very large size; several hundred millions of rows. I need the fastest matching algorithm to fill out values on `Table1.T1c3` values.

Comment: What data type is it? How are you indexing these columns?

Comment: They are strings

Answer (score 0):

*I think* you could abuse `Coalesce()` to do this in the `ON` clause of your join:

```
SELECT table2.c3 + table1.c3
FROM table1
   INNER JOIN table2 
       ON COALESCE(table1.c1, table2.c1) = COALESCE(table2.c1 = table1.c1)
          AND COALESCE(table1.c2, table2.c2) = COALESCE(table2.c2 = table1.c2);
```

That *feels* like it might be speedier than dropping `CASE` all of the over the place or hitting this with a bunch of `OR` conditions but it might be 6 of one half a dozen of the other...

This is assuming that there would never be a null in both `c1` and `c2` of either table at the same time. Otherwise you may end up with some funky cross-join shenanigans.

Comment: `COALESCE(table2.c1 = table1.c1)`? That doesn't seem right.